Calling functions as per device orientation
I am looking for a solution to call different functions as per orientation
if (window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth) {
  alert("You are in portrait mode");
  <Portrait />
}

if (window.innerHeight < window.innerWidth) {
  alert("You are in landscape mode"); 
  <Landscape />
}


Written the following functions
export default function Landscape() {
  return (
    <main>...</main>
  );
}

function Portrait() {
  return (
    <main>...</main>
  );
}

Problem

Every time, only Landscape function getting called (I understand because I mentioned default)
Atleast, I was expecting Portrait function to be called, when device in portrait mode

Please help to get it done

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Landscape() {
 return (
   <main>
   <h1>Landscape Mode</h1>
   {/* Your landscape content */}
   </main>
 );
}

function Portrait() {
 return (
  <main>
  <h1>Portrait Mode</h1>
  {/* Your portrait content */}
 </main>
);
}

 export default function App() {
   const [isLandscape, setIsLandscape] = useState(window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight);

 useEffect(() => {
  function handleResize() {
  setIsLandscape(window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight);
  }

  window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
 }, []);

 return (
   <div>
  {isLandscape ? <Landscape /> : <Portrait />}
   </div>
);

}

As a side note, if this is Next.js, you might want to avoid using window inside the default value for the state since the window object is only accessible from inside effects.

@moonstar-x yes, i am using next.js kindly help, as I am facing referenceerror "window is not defined"

Just replace the inside of the useState with a default value that does not use window. Something like useState(true) to have isLandscape default to true. Additionally, inside the useEffect you should call the handleResize function before the window.addEventListener as well to execute it as soon as the component mounts.

You can also use this custom hook.
It utilizes the new screen.orientation feature instead of checking innerHeight / innerWidth.
As of March 2023, it works across the latest devices and browser versions.
import { useOrientation } from 'react-use';
import './App.css';

const PortraitContent = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Welcome to the portrait mode</h1>
            <p className="content-portrait">Here is some information that's
                specific to portrait mode</p>
        </div>
    );
}

const LandscapeContent = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Welcome to the landscape mode</h1>
            <p className="content-landscape">Here is some information that's
                specific to landscape mode</p>
        </div>
    );
}

const App = () => {
    const { type } = useOrientation();
    return (
        <div>
            {type === 'landscape-primary' ? (
                <LandscapeContent />
            ) : (
                <PortraitContent />
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
export default App;

